# Definition of derivative $f(x) = 3x - \frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: derivatives

$f(x) = 3x - \frac{1}{x^2}$

I am finding this problem to be very tricky:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit joining the $3$ into the other fraction. It just makes your algebra harder/messier.

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3(x+h)-\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}-3x+\frac{1}{x^2}}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3h-\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3h-\frac{x^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}+\frac{(x+h)^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3h+\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3h+\frac{2xh+h^2}{x^2(x+h)^2}}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3h+\frac{h(2x+h)}{x^2(x+h)^2}}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}3+\frac{(2x+h)}{x^2(x+h)^2}$$

$$=3+\frac{2x}{x^2\cdot x^2}$$

$$=3+\frac{2}{x^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint:

Use anothe version of differentiation:

$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}= \lim_{x\to a}\frac{(3x-1/x^2)-(3a-1/a^2)}{x-a}=\cdots=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{3a^2x^2(x-a)-(x-a)(x+a)}{x^2a^2(x-a)}=??$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{3(x+h)-\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}-3x+\frac{1}{x^2}}{h}$$ for the numerator of the right-hand side we obtain
$$\frac{h \left(3 h^2 x^2+6 h x^3+h+3 x^4+2 x\right)}{x^2 (h+x)^2}$$ thus we have $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{3h^2x^2+6hx^3+h+3x^4+2x}{x^2(h+x)^2}$$
now you can calculate the limit